# Backbone.Marionette CollectionView callback when all itemViews have finished rendering?

Tags: marionette

I'm using the marionette `Layout` `.show` to render a `CollectionView` and was wondering if there is a way of detecting when **all** the `ItemView` children have finished rendering?

A simplified version of my code is:

Layout

```
Layouts.Group = Backbone.Marionette.Layout.extend({

    template: Templates.group,

    ...

    regions: {
        header: ".group-header"
        details: ".group-details"
    },

    ...

});
```

CollectionView

```
Views.GroupDetail = Backbone.Marionette.CollectionView.extend({

    itemView: groupDetailRow,

    ...

    onRender: function () {

        // do something here after rendering *all* groupDetailRows of information for group detail section

    }

});
```

ItemView

```
Views.GroupDetailRow = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({

    onRender: function () {

        // single groupDetailRow of information

    }

});
```

.show

```
var details = new Views.GroupDetail();

details.show(new DV.Time.Views.GroupDetail());
```

I noticed in the docs that there is mention of a `.done` function:

```
new MyCollectionView().render().done(function(){
  // all of the children are now rendered. do stuff here.
});
```

Is it possible to use this with the `Layout`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can listen to a "render" event, or provide an "onRender" callback function on the view.

```
MyView = Marionette.CollectionView.extend({

  onRender: function(){
    // the list of items has been rendered. do stuff here
  }

});

var view = new MyView();

view.on("render", function(){
  // the list of items has been rendered. do stuff here
});
```

https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.collectionview.md#render--onrender-event

Comment: Thanks!

If the CollectionView is requesting data via AJAX, would the Layout's onRender function wait until this has been returned before running?

Comment: no - onRender gets called after the "render" function is done. the render function really doesn't care if there are any items in the view, in terms of when it fires that method/event. you would need to listen to the collection's "reset" event to know when it's done fetching.

Comment: Neither solutions (`onRender` and `reset`) worked in my case. - I had to listen to the collection `sync` event instead. (Weirdly enough) it's apparently safe to assume that all items of the `CollectionView` are fully rendered when that event is triggered.

Comment: Thanks @MarcoLazzeri. onRender should consider async tasks.