# Is there a Marionette.js Event that fires after all items in a CollectionView are rendered?

Tags: javascript, marionette

In [Backbone.Marionette.js](http://marionettejs.com/) CollectionViews and CompositeViews, the `onDomRefresh` event fires when the DOM is initially rendered and ALSO any time that an item is added to the view's collection (this contributes to the dynamic / "live" nature of the views).  In my case, I want to run a certain jQuery function, but due to the typical length of the collection, it would be better to only call this function once **at the last render** to prevent excess function calls to something I only want to do once after all models are rendered in the UI.

Is there a Marionette event with the appropriate timing for this use case?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13529407/backbone-marionette-collectionview-callback-when-all-itemviews-have-finished-ren ?
Edit: Oh sorry, didn't see that you were asking for CollectionView.

Comment: No problem, also a `CompositeView` method would work, but **not** an `itemView`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of V2.4.1 http://marionettejs.com/annotated-src/backbone.marionette.html, it's now `render:collection` that you should be listening for after the `CollectionView` is done rendering the children.

```
_renderChildren: function() {
  this.destroyEmptyView();
  this.destroyChildren();

  if (this.isEmpty(this.collection)) {
    this.showEmptyView();
  } else {
    this.triggerMethod('before:render:collection', this);
    this.startBuffering();
    this.showCollection();
    this.endBuffering();
    this.triggerMethod('render:collection', this);

    if (this.children.isEmpty()) {
      this.showEmptyView();
    }
  }
},
```

I would recommend against using mexitalian's answer as checking if `the children.length == the collection.length` will fire twice in the method `onAddChild()`.

Comment: I'm going to assume this is the latest and greatest, please someone let me know if it's wrong as I'm not using Marionette now.

Answer (score 7):

I had been trying to use Erik's solution all afternoon but the "collection:rendered" event is never fired. After trawling though the source I see it does not exist anymore :(

But there is a rather easy way to get the behaviour desired.

From within a CollectionView use the onAddChild callback to do the following:

```
onAddChild : function() {
// Check all the models in the collection have their child views rendered
  if ( this.children.length == this.collection.length ) {
    // Now you could do something like
    this.trigger("collection:rendered");
  }
}
```

It works because the collection count goes up to its new length instantly while the children length is updated one at a time.

Pretty simple, it has made me happy :)
Hope it helps someone else too.

Answer (score 3):

You can listen to "collection:rendered".  Here is what the CollectionView triggers when it is done rendering children:

```
this.triggerMethod("collection:rendered", this);
```

You can use this:

```
this.listenTo(myCollectionView, "collection:rendered", _awesomeCallback);
```

Of course you will need to change the above.

**EDIT**:

Here is the render method for a collection view:

```
render: function(){
    this.isClosed = false;
    this.triggerBeforeRender();
    this._renderChildren();
    this.triggerRendered();
    return this;
  }
```

this.triggerRendered() fires off this.triggerMethod("collection:rendered", this), so the collection will be rendered before "collection:rendered" is triggered.

Comment: This isn't accurate... collection:rendered is fired before any items are rendered. As far as I can tell the only way to know when all items are rendered is to listen for itemview:item:rendered, keep a count and compare it to collection.length

Comment: Added render() method code which shows that "collection:rendered" isn't fired until the children are rendered.